# Adding to a static member field

Tags: java, static, static-methods

I'm having trouble understanding static member fields. I have this piece of code:

Stats.java

```
private static List<Stats> staTest = new ArrayList<Stats>();
private String test, test2;

public Stats() {
    staTest.add(new Stats("foo", "bar"));
}

public Stats(String de, String mo) {
    staTest.add(new Stats(de, mo));
}

public String getTest(int i) {
    return staTest.get(i).test;
}

public void setTest(String t, int i) {
    staTest.get(i).test = t;
}
```

In my other class:

```
private String foo, bar;
Stats sta;

public void something(String f, String b)
{
    sta = new Stats(f, b);
}
```

I get a StackOverflow error on this line: staTest.add(new Stats(de, mo)). Please help me understand static variables and calls. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem has nothing to do with static and all to do with your creating a new Stats object within the Stats object constructor. This set up will end up creating endless Stats objects until you run out of stack memory and your program throws a StackOverflow error. Don't do this.

Instead perhaps add `this`

```
public Stats() {
    staTest.add(this);
}

public Stats(String de, String mo) {
    this.test = de;
    this.test2 = mo;
    staTest.add(this);
}
```

Comment: The default constructor call just makes test and test2 null or blank strings?

Comment: @c.C: the default constructor will leave test and test2 null. If you want them blank, then you will need to assign them as such.